# changing data on jsp page using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web

Basically, i need show on 1 jsp page 10 unsorted arrays, and then after clicking on button, sort them and display 10 sorted arrays, so on 1 page have to be 20 arrays(ten sorted and ten unsorted). Hopefully i describe it clear for you. 
Im using Spring MVC/JSP.
Here is my home.jsp page

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<P>   current arrays: <br>
 <c:forEach items="${list}" var="arr">
       <c:forEach items="${arr}" var="elem">
          ${elem} 
       </c:forEach> <br>
    </c:forEach>
  </P>
  
  <br>
    sorted arrays:
  <form:form action = "sort">
  <input type="submit" value="Sort" />
   <c:forEach items="${sortedList2}" var="arr">
      <c:forEach items="${arr}" var="elem">
          ${elem} 
      </c:forEach> <br>
    </c:forEach>

  </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {


private AlgorithmModel algo = new AlgorithmModel();

private List<Integer[]> list = algo.getList();

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);


@ModelAttribute("list")
public List<Integer[]> getList() {
return list;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(ModelMap model) {
return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/sort", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String sort(@ModelAttribute("list") ArrayList<Integer[]> list, ModelMap model) {
List<Integer[]> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(list);
algo.sortList(list2);
model.put("sortedList2", list2);
return "home";
}
```

}

And finally here is my AlgorithmModel, to perform sorting and generate List:

```
public class AlgorithmModel {
private Random random = new Random();
private List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

private List<Integer[]> randomGenerate() {
List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
int size = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.add(generateArr(size));
    size++;
}
return list;
}

private Integer[] generateArr(int n) {
Integer[] arr = new Integer[n];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = random.nextInt(101);
}
return arr;
}

public AlgorithmModel() {
list = randomGenerate();
}

public List<Integer[]> getList() {
return list;
}

public void sortList(List<Integer[]> list) {
for (Integer[] integers : list) {
    sort(integers);
}
}

private void sort(Integer[] arr) {
  //some sort algorithm
}
}
```

So i think it should work like this:
-In controller we generate list with 10 random arrays
-using @ModelAtribute and pull this list on the page
-click button and sort our list inside sort method

but as the result i get:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1el6h.png)

both lists get sorted, but first one shoudnt.
How can i make this work?
P.S. im new in Spring MVC, and ive wasted 4 hours already, so sry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is not a spring-mvc question but more like a Java question.
The problem you have is, even you are creating a new list before sorting; both of the lists are still pointing to the same Integer array. You should deep clone your integer array from the initial list and create the second list with this new array instance before sorting.